# How to specify image quality for GeoStyling "GeoImage" in GeoGraphics?

Tags: plotting, geography, geodesy

I am creating plots (`ContourPlot`, `SmoothDensityHistogram`, etc.) that I then need to project onto geographic polygons. When this is done with  `GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", _}]` the images are projected onto `GeoGraphics` polygons have greatly reduced image quality to the actual plots.

How can the quality of the image in `GeoGraphics` be specified?

Minimal example:

```
adOK = AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Oklahoma", "UnitedStates"}];
geoBounds = Round[GeoBounds[adOK], .1];

cp = ContourPlot[Cos[long] + Cos[lat], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Reverse@MapThread[Prepend, {geoBounds, {lat, long}}]], 
  AspectRatio -> Divide @@ Reverse@Apply[Subtract, Reverse[geoBounds, {1, 2}], 2],
  Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image]

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Gray, GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", cp}], adOK["Polygon"]}, 
  GeoBackground -> None, GeoRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

As you can see above the quality of the image in the `GeoGraphics` is many times lower than the image quality of the plot. How can the quality of the image in `GeoGraphics` be specified?

Comment: Why not preprocess `cp` with `Rasterize[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yup. That will do it. 0_o

Comment: No. Increasing Rasterize with RasterSize does not affect the output of the GeoGraphics.